# Buchwald-Hartwig coupling troubleshooting

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis

I am conducting a synthesis using below scheme.

[image: reaction scheme]

And Below is some information about my reaction history.

- The basic condition is 1 eq of 1-aza-18-crown-6, 1.4 eq of 3-bromothiophene, 1 mol% of DavePhos Pd G4, 1 mol% of DavePhos, 2 eq of NaOtBu, toluene as solvent, and conducted at 100 ℃ for 24 h.
- I chose the P ligand as DavePhos referring to [this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo005577d).
- After 24 h, the reaction mixture is cooled to room temperature, taken up into 100 mL of dichloromethane, filtered through Celite, concentrated using rotovap, and dried in vacuum.
- As I checked the GC/MS spectrum of the sample, the peak of 1-aza-18-crown-6 (SM2) is relatively much larger than that of 3-bromothiophene (SM1), and the product peak is also very small. That is, conversion is too low.
- Below is the GC/MS spectrum. The unassigned peaks are unknown compounds or maybe impurities in GC column. The mass spectrum of each peak was omitted.

[image: GC-MS spectrum1]

- As I decreased the amount of catalyst and temperature, no product peak was observed.
- As I increased the amount of catalyst to 3 mol% and temperature to 120 ℃, the peak of SM1 was largely decreased, but also the peak of product was.
- Below is the GC/MS spectrum in the case of 3 mol% of catalyst loading. The unassigned peaks are unknown compounds or maybe impurities in GC column. The mass spectrum of each peak was omitted.

[image: GC-MS spectrum2-1]
[image: GC-MS spectrum2-2]
[image: GC-MS spectrum2-3]

My doubtful point is that there are no remarkable byproduct peaks although the peak of SM1 is very small in contrast to the fact that the peak of SM2 is very large. In the case of 3 mol% catalyst loading the peak of bithiophene, which is the representative byproduct of Buchwald-Hartwig reaction, was observed, but it is also very small. If there were any large byprodut peaks, I would try to find a solution, however this situation is uninterpretable. What was going on in my reaction mixture?

Comment: In normal conditions there are about 20 different reasons why a Buchwald-Hartwig amination didn't go well, but your unique substrate makes me think of a 21st reason - could the coordination of $\ce{Na+}$ by the azacrown somehow be influencing its reactivity? It might make the N-H substantially more acidic, and my vague understanding is that acidic N-H makes for poor BH coupling partners. I wonder what would happen if you had a strong non-alkali metal base (assuming such bases have been successfully used in BH aminations). That said, when hearing hooves, think horses, not zebras I guess.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Makes sense, in fact there were observed two spots from pure aza crown solution in TLC using Dragendorff reagent. And as far as I know the crown spot and crown+cation spot have different Rf values in TLC. But then I can't understand that where all the bromothiophene were consumed and where they went. Also, in the paper I linked, the condition using toluene and NaOtBu was successful in synthesizing N-aryl aza crown ether.

Comment: 3-Bromothiophene is reasonably volatile. If it doesn't react, you may easily have vacuumed it out.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Ohh...... That can be a reason...

Comment: @KrangLee  Have you run a sample of the 3-Br-thiophene starting material on the GC-MS? Does it show up well?

Comment: @Waylander I have tried only DIP-MS, but not GC/MS using pure 3-bromothiophene.

Comment: @KrangLee I think it is worth doing to get a handle on how well it shows up on the GC-MS. It is a technique that can sometimes give confusing results because conpounds do not show up as well as you expect.

Comment: @Waylander I would check it, Thank you. Also I think that I should check vacuum dried 3-bromothiophene sample too.